# Динамическое создание многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день!

Решается следующая задача: на вход подается XML, которую необходимо по ключу (в данном примере это OptionName) схлопнуть в массив. Например:

```
    <AdditionalOptionList>
       <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Кост центр</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>12345</OptionValue> 
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory> 
    </AdditionalOption>
    <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Кост центр</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>1234</OptionValue>
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory>
    </AdditionalOption>
    <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Табельный номер</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>аб</OptionValue>
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory>
    </AdditionalOption>
    <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Табельный номер</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>абв</OptionValue>
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory>
    </AdditionalOption>
    <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Табельный номер</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>абвг</OptionValue>
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory>
    </AdditionalOption>
    <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Тип поездки</OptionName>
        <OptionValue/>
        <OptionMandatory>false</OptionMandatory>
    </AdditionalOption>
            <AdditionalOption>
        <OptionName>Табельный номер</OptionName>
        <OptionValue>аб</OptionValue>
        <OptionMandatory>true</OptionMandatory> </AdditionalOption> </AdditionalOptionList>
```

Для решения хочу реализовать алгоритм, который проходится по всей XML, создавая многомерный массив, в котором первый ключ это option name, а на втором уровне массив из option value.
Т.е. на выходе хочу получить массив вида:

```
Array ( [Кост центр] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1]=>1234) [Табельный номер] => Array ( [0] => аб [1]=>абв [2]=>абвг) [Тип поездки] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

Для реализация алгоритма написал следующий код:

```
    $array_option_name=array();
    foreach($xml_array[0]->children() as $XML_child){
        foreach($XML_child->children() as $XML_child_lev2){
            if ($XML_child_lev2->getname()=='OptionName'){
                    $value = (string) $XML_child_lev2;
                    if (array_search($value,$array_option_name)===false){
                        $array_option_name=array_merge($array_option_name,array($value=>array()));
                    }
            }
            if ($XML_child_lev2->getname()=='OptionValue'){
                    $option_value = (string) $XML_child_lev2;
                    array_push($array_option_name[$value],$option_value);
            }
        }
    }
```

print_r($array_option_name) после моего кода возращает:

```
Array ( [Кост центр] => Array ( [0] => 1234 ) [Табельный номер] => Array ( [0] => аб ) [Тип поездки] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

Т.е. я записываю, только последний элемент, вместо всех. В чем может быть ошибка?

Спасибо!

для понимания print_r($xml_array) возвращает:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [AdditionalOption] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [comment] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [OptionName] => Кост центр [OptionValue] => 12345 [OptionMandatory] => true ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Кост центр [OptionValue] => 1234 [OptionMandatory] => true ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Табельный номер [OptionValue] => аб [OptionMandatory] => true ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Табельный номер [OptionValue] => абв [OptionMandatory] => true ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Табельный номер [OptionValue] => абвг [OptionMandatory] => true ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Тип поездки [OptionValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [OptionMandatory] => false ) [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OptionName] => Табельный номер [OptionValue] => аб [OptionMandatory] => true ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с использованием [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php) вам не надо перебирать потомков и сравнивать названия узлов, просто обращайтесь к им по имени и все.

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("./data.xml");
$result = [];
foreach($data->AdditionalOption as $opt){
    $name = (string) $opt->OptionName;
    if(!array_key_exists($name, $result)){
        $result[$name] = [];
    }
    $result[$name][] = (string) $opt->OptionValue;
}
```

а для получения строкового значения, приводите их к типу `string` явно.

*зы: на выходе имеем массив с повторами, для `табельный номер` значение `аб` встречается 2 раза. Вы в своем коде никак не пытаетесь проверить подобный случай, поэтому не совсем ясно, нужны эти дубликаты или нет*

Comment: Добрый день!  Спасибо, помогло, на выходе получил то что хотел. Однако конструкцию $result = [] и аналогичные заменил на $result=array(); В противном случае получал ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['.

Comment: @Дмитрий это потому что версия пхп у вас какая-то древняя

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуем xml в массив и далее просто пересобираем так как нам нужно:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE)['AdditionalOption'];
$result = [];

array_map(function($item)use(&$result){
    $v = $item['OptionValue']?:''
    $result[$item['OptionName']][$v] = $v;
},$array);

print_r($result);
```

На выход как ты и хотел :

```
[Кост центр] => Array
    (
        [12345] => 12345
        [1234] => 1234
    )

[Табельный номер] => Array
    (
        [аб] => аб
        [абв] => абв
        [абвг] => абвг
    )

[Тип поездки] => Array
    (
        [] =>
    )
```

Comment: вам не кажется что json здесь выступает в роли костыля?

Comment: неа, это наверное самый популярный способ преобразовать xml в массив, так сказать easy метод.

Comment: о да, `mysql_query() or die()` тоже популярно, однако, это достаточно низкосортное программирование. На больших данных вы в 3 раза увеличиваете объем работы по построению дерева, а в добавок вам из всего этого нужны не все данные.

Comment: Сравнение использования устаревших конструкций с реально полезным триксом не месту как то. Про реально большие данные по условию никто не писал. Массивы в php это то что реально делает его таким популярным, в большинстве случаев работа с ними гораздо более гибкая и удобная.

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо, подобное решение сохранил, думаю пригодится в будущем. Однако вариант teran действительно выглядит более быстрым и изящным.